# cpu scheduling SRTF

Tags: operating-system, cpu, scheduling

SRTF cpu scheduling is given in 3 parts , a process spend CPU BURST TIME followed by an IO BURST TIME followed by a CPU BURST TIME , confusion is that on which burst time SRTF need to be applied ,on a TOTAL CPU BURST TIME or just on THE CPU BURST TIME GIVEN IN 1ST CPU RUN seperately followed by on the 2nd cpu burst time seperately ?

Answer (score 0):

These type of problems are usually asked when using RR scheduling and rarely asked when using SRTF.

If you really want an answer,since I/O-bound job should always have higher priority than CPU-bound job to get CPU.It is make sense to use first part to calculate because this allows I/O operation start earlier.

Comment: IO will be started of a process as soon as first cpu run gets completed , cnfusion is in allcting cpu to a process acrding to seperate burst time or total burst time : as ex : P1 has CPU1 =2 , IO=3 , CPU2=3  and P2 has CPU1 = 1 , IO =4 , CPU2=5  , SO now if we apply srtf on total burst time then P1 will be allctd cpu and if we apply srtf on burst time of cpu1 only then P2 will be allctd cpu first , so answers will be different in both the cases !